# How to add timestamp to each request in uvicorn logs?

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

When I run my FastAPI server using uvicorn:

```
uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --log-level info
```

The log I get after running the server:

```
INFO:     Started server process [405098]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Connect to database...
INFO:     Successfully connected to the database!
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     122.179.31.158:54604 - "GET /api/hello_world?num1=5&num2=10 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

How do I get the time stamp along with the request logging? Like:

```
INFO:     "2020-07-16:23:34:78" - 122.179.31.158:54604 - "GET /api/hello_world?num1=5&num2=10 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

Comment: You can use [**`--log-config`**](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/) to specify the [log configuration file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use Uvicorn's **`LOGGING_CONFIG`**

```
import uvicorn
from uvicorn.config import LOGGING_CONFIG
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

def run():
    LOGGING_CONFIG["formatters"]["default"]["fmt"] = "%(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(levelprefix)s %(message)s"
    uvicorn.run(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Which will return uvicorn log with the timestamp

```
2020-08-20 02:33:53,765 [uvicorn.error] INFO:     Started server process [107131]
2020-08-20 02:33:53,765 [uvicorn.error] INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
2020-08-20 02:33:53,765 [uvicorn.error] INFO:     Application startup complete.
2020-08-20 02:33:53,767 [uvicorn.error] INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: `LOGGING_CONFIG["formatters"]["default"]["datefmt"] = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
` is also useful.

Comment: `LOGGING_CONFIG["formatters"]["access"]["fmt"] = '%(asctime)s %(levelprefix)s %(client_addr)s - "%(request_line)s" %(status_code)s'
`

Comment: This is what I used! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8):

You can create a ***dict logger config*** and initialize the same using [**`dictConfig`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) function in your main application.

```
#main.py

from logging.config import dictConfig
from config import log_config

from fastapi import FastAPI

dictConfig(log_config.sample_logger)

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

#config/log_config.py

sample_logger = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "access": {
            "()": "uvicorn.logging.AccessFormatter",
            "fmt": '%(levelprefix)s %(asctime)s :: %(client_addr)s - "%(request_line)s" %(status_code)s',
            "use_colors": True
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "access": {
            "formatter": "access",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "uvicorn.access": {
            "handlers": ["access"],
            "level": "INFO",
            "propagate": False
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! And it seems the less changing from my standpoint

Answer (score 5):

Combined the answers of @Yagiz Degirmenci and @HappyFace, I got this code.

```py
LOGGING_CONFIG["formatters"]["default"]["fmt"] = "%(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(levelprefix)s %(message)s"
LOGGING_CONFIG["formatters"]["access"][
    "fmt"] = '%(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(levelprefix)s %(client_addr)s - "%(request_line)s" %(status_code)s'
```

The log likes this:

```
2021-03-31 18:38:22,728 [uvicorn.error] INFO:     Started server process [21824]
2021-03-31 18:38:22,729 [uvicorn.error] INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
2021-03-31 18:38:22,729 [uvicorn.error] INFO:     Application startup complete.
2021-03-31 18:38:22,729 [uvicorn.error] INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2021-03-31 18:38:26,359 [uvicorn.access] INFO:     127.0.0.1:51932 - "POST /limit HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

Answer (score 3):

Was able to achieve the same by not running the server from terminal using uvicorn command.
But by running the server using run function of uvicorn package.

While surfing the web for the solution, I ended up on this [issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1508), where [Dylan Anthony](https://github.com/dbanty) has written the solution using run function of uvicorn package.

Although, it will still be good to know how to achieve the same using uvicorn command.